# Talend Open Studio Spatial

Tags: spatial-join

I'm using the spatial extension for Talend (Ex-TOS SDI) and i'm experiencing a blocking issue. I'm trying to make what ESRI call a Spatial Join and I can't find a proper solution to do that ( transferring attributes from one shape to another based on the location of the features).

Does anyone tried (and succeed!) to make a spatial join on Talend?